# How can I access to a element of a svm.pred object?

Tags: svm

I'm trying to predict the class of a sample (predict the quality of a wine, in levels of 4-5-6-7-8) with a SVM multiclass. When i predict a single sample in this way:

> svm.pred <- predict(svm.model,testset[18,-12])

The reponse is this:

> svm.pred
>
> 3254
>
> 6
>
> Levels: 4 5 6 7 8

How can I access to the number "6" to store it in a variable?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

svm.pred is a factor.

```
library(e1071)
data(iris)
attach(iris)
model = svm(Species ~ ., data = iris)
pred = predict(model, x)

head(pred)
     1      2      3      4      5      6 
setosa setosa setosa setosa setosa setosa 
Levels: setosa versicolor virginica
```

To access the elements of a factor, use `labels()`

```
labels(head(pred))

## output
[1] "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "6"
```

And to access the levels, use `levels()`

```
levels(pred)

## output
[1] "setosa"     "versicolor" "virginica"
```

Comment: The output of "labels()" is the set of all the labels in the factor. I want to get and store in a variable the "prediction" (in this case 6) for the sample (in this case, the nº 3254).

Comment: I might be misunderstanding, but wouldn't ```labels(svm.pred)[1]``` work?

Comment: it return "3254", the label of the sample that I am predicting. And levels(svm.pred)[1] return "3", the first level in the factor

Comment: I see - you want the level. Try this: ```as.character(svm.pred)[1]```